# How to search two meta values from same single column and table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I make a custom search in WordPress. There are three fields for searching.

> 1. Age
> 2. Location
> 3. Post Title

[image]

Post Title is searched from `wp_posts > post_title` field and location and age are custom meta fields `y_age, y_activity_locations`. So there is 6 scenarios of searching.

If user enter:

> 1. Enter Title or
> 2. Select Location or
> 3. Select Age or
> 4. Enter Title and Select Location or
> 5. Enter Title and Select Age or
> 6. Select Location and Select Age

My first 5 (Five) scenarios are working perfectly but my 6th scenario is not working because it comes from same table (`wp_postmeta`) and same column but two different values.

So I tried this query:

```
Select y_posts.*, y_meta.*
From wp_posts As y_posts
Inner Join wp_postmeta As y_meta
On y_posts.ID = y_meta.post_id
Where y_posts.post_type = 'download'
And y_posts.post_status = 'publish'
And y_meta.meta_key = 'y_activity_locations' 
And y_meta.meta_value Like '%Armidale%'
And y_meta.meta_key = 'y_age'
And y_meta.meta_value Like '%3 to 5%'
```

The query is not working because I think sever confused two values from same column.

```
Select y_posts.*, y_meta.*
    From wp_posts As y_posts
    Inner Join wp_postmeta As y_meta
    On y_posts.ID = y_meta.post_id
    Where y_posts.post_type = 'download'
    And y_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    And y_meta.meta_key = 'y_activity_locations' 
    And y_meta.meta_value Like '%Armidale%'
    Or y_meta.meta_key = 'y_age'
    Or y_meta.meta_value Like '%3 to 5%'
```

This query works and it gives me only age or location data but i want search both values at a same time.

I also tried sub query (Never tried before)

```
Select y_posts.*, y_meta.*
From wp_posts As y_posts
Inner Join wp_postmeta As y_meta
On y_posts.ID = y_meta.post_id
Where y_posts.post_type = 'download'
And y_posts.post_status = 'publish'
And y_meta.meta_key = 'y_activity_locations' 
And y_meta.meta_value Like '%Armidale%'
And (Select yy_meta.* From wp_postmeta As yy_meta Where yy_meta.meta_key = 'y_age'
And yy_meta.meta_value Like '%3 to 5%')
```

But it gives me this error

> ## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

So please guide me how can I get two values from same column.

Please give me only query suggestions not any other solutions.

Comment: If you only want query suggestions then why have you tagged this with php?

Comment: I means that no plugin suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following query :

```
    Select y_posts.*, y_meta.*
    From wp_posts As y_posts
    Inner Join wp_postmeta As y_meta
    On y_posts.ID = y_meta.post_id
    Where y_posts.post_type = 'download'
    And y_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    And (
        (y_meta.meta_key = 'y_activity_locations' 
        And y_meta.meta_value Like '%Armidale%')
        Or (y_meta.meta_key = 'y_age'
        And y_meta.meta_value Like '%3 to 5%')
    )
```

Comment: your answer working perfectly .... please just tell me the logic of this in your answer And y_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    And ( ) ... Why we wrap our meta keys and values in one more () ... I accept your answer in a few minutes ... thanx :)

Comment: You most welcome and thanks for up vote. I have wrap meta_key and meta_value because we need and condition between them and we need OR condition on combination of them as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You try, wordpress query

```
<?php 
$argsCat = array(   
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,              
    'post_type'        => 'download',
    'meta_key'         => 'y_activity_locations',
    'meta_value'       => '%Armidale%',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'y_age',
            'value' => '3',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'y_age',
            'value' => '5',
            'compare' => '<='
        )
    ),

);  
$normal_array = get_posts($argsCat);

?>
```